# most common config flags for installing R from source on 64-bit Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu

I'm convinced that using Dirk's package is the best way to install and maintain R on an Ubuntu system. But I want to have some fun and get used to installing R from source.

What are the most common configure flags to use when installing?

Also, if I want to install 2.14.1 and I have 2.14.0 currently installed (which was installed from source), should I first uninstall 2.14.0?

Comment: The R users here will probably be sympathetic to your question, but we're not the only ones voting, so... since this _technically_ isn't a programming question, you may want to delete it and re-post (on superuser?) to avoid down-votes and close-votes.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich ah, thanks for the warning. Well, I'll leave it and see what happens. If it is closed I'll post on superuser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a recent thread somewhere about having several versions---one from the `apt-get` repo, one in `/usr/local`. Try to find that...

Otherwise, I will roll up 2.14.1 on Friday morning, Michael will do his magic and the repo will have .deb packages of 2.14.1 'real soon', sometimes within a day.

Lastly, you can see which flags are used by getting the package sources for which you just  do `apt-get source r-base` (and that works for any Debian/Ubuntu package that way if you have source references in `apt`'s file.

*Edit:* By the way, regarding the '64-bit' aspect of your question: Nada.  We don't do anything differently.  It is "merely" the host OS being more generous with resources.  But R finds all it needs to know on its own via its `configure` etc logic.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have Ubuntu in front of me, but I don't remember seeing which flags are used when using `apt-get source`. How do I do that?

Comment: Navigate the web site at `packages.ubuntu.com` and just look at the `diff.gz`, looking for the file `debian/rules` -- that method also works for every package (and you should look under the source package name, e.g. `r-base`).

Comment: great- thank you! I wonder if `configure-stamp` is the best thing to search for in the `diff.gz`. Thanks also for the edit, that's good to know.